# Does Rails cache templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I assume yes, and some tests point to yes, but I'd like to find the documentations that says Rails caches (unevaluated) templates in memory.

That is, for any `.erb`, `.sass`, `.jbuilder`, etc template Rails will:

1. **read the template from file, only once**
2. **retrieve the template from memory when needed**
3. apply data to the template on every invocation unless the *generated output* is cached.

All template/cache searches and documentation seem to be focused on point #3. And development Rails flags enable/disable *class-caching*. But finding docs that verify claim #1/#2 seem illusive. Does Rails re-read template files every time and rely on OS level file caching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question and did some hunting.

[Yes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb#L64) - Rails caches templates.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the fact cache takes locals as key, and I would say then that unevaluated template is not cached.

Answer (score 0):

In production, it will if you add calls to do so.  It is disabled in development mode however you can edit it to cache in development as well in your config/environments/development.rb file by changing the following line from false to true:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

In production, Rails has 3 main methods of caching when it comes to views (there are also rails methods for db caching).  Page-caching, action-caching, and fragment-caching.  To implement these in Rails you can use certain helpers like the `caches_page` macro-style method in a controller.  This will cache the view in its entirety to disk with no further involvement by the Rails dispatcher. This should only be used when the page is completely static and has no dynamic content.  `caches_action` and  fragment caching provide much more fine-grained implementations and probably make up the majority of use-cases in Rails.